# Why box c will not move down after increase margin-top

Tags: css

You can find sample code at http://jsfiddle.net/ryamx/2/

```
#c {
    width:110px;
    height:57px;
    border:1px solid blue;
    margin-top:250px;
    clear:right;

}
```

My purpose is move box c by change value of margin-top. 
It have clear property,  then it does not work.
Why?

Simply how "clear" effect element behavior

Answer (score 1):

try `clear:both;`

```
<div id="b"> b</div>
<div style="width:100%;clear:both;"></div>
<div id="c">c </div>
```

[**Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8Nj37/)

Comment: That has the same effect as `clear: right` since `#b` is only floating right. The question is *why*.

Comment: [When applied to non-floating blocks, it moves the border edge of the element down until it is below the margin edge of all relevant floats. This movement (when it happens) causes margin collapsing not to occur.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/clear)

Comment: @BoltClock offtopic..could you tell me difference between sha512 and whirlpool ?

Comment: Why not ask it as a separate question? :)

Comment: i think it will vague/not constructive /not-real question ..isnt it?

Comment: You need to do your research first and foremost, then post a question if you do not understand what you've found. If people don't see that you've made any effort to search (Google search `sha512 whirlpool`), that's when they downvote and vote to close. You should also avoid asking things like "which is better" "which is faster" and so on, and be specific in what you're intending to use these hashing algorithms for, to avoid being closed as not constructive. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: Maybe question is not clearly. i know "clear" causes margin collapsing not to occur. just want to understand how margin-top work when have clear.
my understand is that margin-top will be distance between top edge of box c and top of box a. then increase margin-top, box c will move. actually no.

Answer (score 0):

**Actually its margin-collapsing basically see the attached image**

[image]

so we can remove that `margin-collapsing` through `float`
Give the `float:left;` to your id **#C**

**CSS**

```
#c {
    width:110px;
    height:57px;
    border:1px solid blue;
    margin-top:250px;
    clear:both;
    float:left;

}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ryamx/9/)

Now see the updated image its taking `margin` after **#b**

[image]

Comment: Or you can remove it through `clear`, which is what is being asked in the question...

Comment: actually NullPointer you answer is also fine but you are making a one extra div extra markup and i tried via only css with existing id.....